# How can I utilise known label consistency in classification

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, labeling

This is a problem that I have experienced in multiple domains but most recently in identifying bird species from audio data. I have 300, 5 minute audio files with corresponding species labels (10 species).

To build a classifier, I split the audio files in 10 second windows and build a CNN on the spectrograms. This achieves a 60% accuracy. To get an overall label for each 5 minute segment, I take the modal predicted label of all windows in the segment, which allows for an accuracy of about 70%.

My question; is there a 'smarter' way to combine the window labels into the overall label? And, is there a name for this problem, so that I can find research on it (it seems like such a common problem, I assume it is well researched).

Methods like HMM and RNN's work, but as far as I know they require viewing the entire segment as one bit of training data, which means I only have 300 samples which is not enough.
A simplistic approach I have tried is creating a second classifier that takes the predicted class of the closest *n* samples as features, but this doesn't increase performance.